# Wrong coordinations for Google maps app inventor

Tags: maps

I am trying to make an app to display one address in Google Maps but when I press the button to maps it displays the marker two to three roads in wrong direction.

Is there any one have's the same problem?

[image: the activitystarter]
[image: the addresse's]

Comment: show your code please in whatever language you do it

Comment: i put some photos the first is the activity starter and the second are the addresse's i have the same problem to all the other input's